# How to find most common color using hive query?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a following table

```
name  red  black  white
US      1    1      1
UK      0    1      0
EU      1    1      0
AUS     0    0      0
```

Now, I need to find which color is the most common?
I got the count of all the color using following query.

```
select colorName,count(name) as total
from
(select
case
when red == 1 then 'red'
when black == 1 then 'black'
end as colorName, name from countrytable)a
group by colorName;
```

This will give following output:

```
red black white
2   3     1
```

But I want to get the most common value which is "black". How can I do this in Hive?

```
Desired output:
black
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another step to order/sort by descending order of the counts and limit it to the top 1 record.

```
select colorName,count(name) as total
from
    (select
       case
           when red == 1 then 'red' 
           when black == 1 then 'black'
       end as colorName, name from countrytable)a
group by colorName
ORDER BY count(name) DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: How can we do the same thing using Pig queries?